# Story about colonists of one of jupiters moons, with frail sibling that died during crisis

Tags: story-identification

I'm pretty sure that this was an entire book, written before the 90's, the protagonist was a teenage male, and his family was emigrating to one of the moons of Jupiter. When they got there they found that the younger sibling couldn't take the lack of pressure, so had to live in a sealed room with higher pressure.
They were farmers, and he had this plow which broke up the stony surface. There was a crisis, and the sealed room broke and the child inside died. I think the rest of the family went back or left, but the boy stayed to continue the colonization.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's [Farmer in the Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farmer_in_the_Sky) by Robert A. Heinlein.

**When they got there they found that the younger sibling couldn't take the lack of pressure, so had to live in a sealed room with higher pressure.**

> When the Lermers are finally reunited on their own homestead, they build their house with a pressurized room for Peggy.

**There was a crisis, and the sealed room broke and the child inside died.**

> One day, a rare alignment of all of Jupiter's major moons causes a devastating moon quake which damages most of the buildings. Peggy is seriously injured when her room suffers an explosive decompression

Comment: Thanks... I guess I got the 'they leave' part wrong, but they do consider leaving :)

Comment: I forgot that Peggy dies :(

Comment: Fun fact: because of orbital resonances among the four big moons, they never line up.

Comment: OP probably remembers the narrator saying to Peggy, “If you do have to go back to Earth, I'll go too.”